# React-Navigation and installation error and first-usage

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I am new to react-native or you can say new to React and I am working on react-native navigation I have installed all the required libraries as instructed in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started but when I am running my code it is giving an error as '@react-navigation/native could not be found within the project or in this directories.' What should I do is there any way to get started with my code? Help me[image: This is the error I am getting in my emmulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed your app following the react native cli guide you might want to try running

`gradle clean`

in your android folder und then try to run your app in the emulator again.

On my first steps with react native I stumpled upon the same issue. :-)

Comment: "gradle :  The term 'gradle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." this is what it is showing on terminal

Comment: Sorry for being unclear about that. In your terminal firstly change over to your android folder (with powershell: `cd .\android`, with bash: `cd ./android`). Than execute `./gradle clean`.